# Css before/after selector content can't contain the same attribute more than once

Tags: css, attributes, css-content

It seems that the content of a before / after selector can't contain the same attribute more than once.

Example:
Let's say we have a div with the name "24".

When writing this:

```
content: attr(name) ' of ' attr(name);
```

the result is not "24 of 24", but "24 of". The second 24 is ignored.

If I change the second attribute into a different attribute then both attributes work, for example;

```
content: attr(name) ' of ' attr(data-size);
```

Both attributes with the value "24" result in "24 of 24".

Any idea why the same attribute can not be used multiple times or any idea how to make that work for a text line like this?

Comment: Can you add a demo to reproduce your issue please. Its working for me here http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s0Lsntmf/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake, a CSS mystery. Now I try it again and it just works! This does not explain anything, but I assume the cause of failing was something else.... Also thanks web-tiki for your jsfiddle to clarify! My question is solved.